# ¿Qué datos puedo obtener y manipular mediante un audio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

He estado leyendo sobre NLP (Neuro-linguistic Programming), Speech Recognition, entre otras cosas para poder leer un audio y extraer la voz humana. Dentro de lo que he leído, sigo sin entender como obtienen estos valores dentro de un audio.wav:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es el promedio de frecuencia (meanFreq), desviacion estandar de frecuencia (sd). Lo no entiendo es, como se pueden obtener esos valores mediante un analisis del audio (como obtenerlos sin necesidad de usar una libreria en especifico).

**¿Como puedo obtener los valores de la tabla de arriba sin necesidad de una libreria?**

Mi objetivo es poder leer esos valores para entrenar una RNA para poder distinguir los generos de voz. Identificar la voz humana en un audio y extraerlo, es para un proyecto escolar y me gustaria saber como podria ir avanzando de poco en poco.

Comment: Transformar un audio (que se extiende en el dominio del tiempo) en una suma de senoides (que se extienden en el dominio de las frencuencias) se hace mediante una transformada de Fourier. La implementación de esta transformada no es trivial, y además es computacionalmente costosa. Hacerla directamente en python sin uso de librerías sería tremendamente lento. Te recomiendo que uses `numpy` que implementa la transformada rápida de Fourier (fft), además en C, para una alta velocidad de ejecución.

Comment: No obstante, si no quieres usar `numpy`, puedes encontrar por internet algunas implementaciones de la FFT en python puro, como [esta](https://github.com/rh314/pure-py-fft/blob/master/fft.py)